# Queries on Java Future and RejectionHandler

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, future, threadpoolexecutor

I had some queries regarding `Future` usage. Please go through below example before addressing my queries.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/01/how-to-use-future-and-futuretask-in-Java.html

1. The main purpose of using thread pools & `Executors` is to execute task asynchronously without blocking main thread. But once you use `Future`, it is blocking calling thread. Do we have to create separate new thread/thread pool to analyse the results of `Callable` tasks? OR is there any other good solution?
2. Since `Future` call is blocking the caller, is it worth to use this feature? If I want to analyse the result of a task, I can have synchronous call and check the result of the call without `Future`.
3. What is the best way to handle Rejected tasks with usage of `RejectionHandler`? If a task is rejected, is it good practice to submit the task to another Thread or ThreadPool Or submit the same task to current `ThreadPoolExecutor` again?

Please correct me if my thought process is wrong about this feature.

Comment: Futures do *not* block the calling thread. Guess why there is a *loop* in the code example you have linked? Because `isDone` does *not* wait. Though the code example polling `isDone` in a loop is still bad coding style. If you want to wait, you can use `get` and if you don’t want the caller thread to be blocked, you can [specify a timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: Look at the [documentation of `RejectedExecutionHandler`, “All Known Implementing Classes”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html) for suggestions for handling strategies.

Comment: Is there any API from Future to get notified when the result is available as time-out is not serving the purpose completely? If that is not available, is it best not to use Future & execute the task synchronously in caller thread itself?

Comment: If you want to schedule an on-completion action, [`CompletableFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer by making me aware of this class. I will explore my code with CompletableFuture

Comment: Your comment is answer for this question. I cannot make this comment as "Accepted answer" since your suggestion was not posted as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about performing an action when an asynchronous action has been done. `Future`s on the other hand are good if you have an unrelated activity which you can perform while the asynchronous action is running. Then you may regularly poll the action represented by the `Future` via `isDone()` and do something else if not or call the blocking `get()` if you have no more unrelated work for your current thread.

If you want to schedule an on-completion action without blocking the current thread, you may instead use [`CompletableFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) which offers such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is the solution for queries 1 and 2 as suggested by @**Holger**

I want to update about `RejectedExecutionHandler` mechanism regarding query 3.

Java provides four types of Rejection Handler policies as per [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

1. In the default `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy`, the handler throws a runtime `RejectedExecutionException` upon rejection.
2. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, the thread that invokes execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are submitted.
3. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy`, a task that cannot be executed is simply dropped.
4. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy`, if the executor is not shut down, the task at the head of the work queue is dropped, and then execution is retried (which can fail again, causing this to be repeated.)

`CallerRunsPolicy`: If you have more tasks in task queue, using this policy will degrade the performance. You have to be careful since reject tasks will be executed by main thread itself. If Running the rejected task is critical for your application and you have limited task queue, you can use this policy.

`DiscardPolicy`: If discarding a non-critical event does not bother you, then you can use this policy.

`DiscardOldestPolicy`: Discard the oldest job and try to resume the last one

If none of them suits your need, you can implement your own `RejectionHandler`.